# Overlay DIV - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, overlay

I'm showing a Div when users click on **Add User**

how can i make it as overlay, i mean users should not be able to select anything from the background content...only the Add User form(div) should be Active

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[CakePHP Modal Window Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652747/cakephp-modal-window-example) both anwers here are valid in my opinion.

Use jquery or the js framework of your choice to make an AJAX request and to open a modal window. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: i created a Add user div and opening the div upon onclick event
after the ajax request is completed i'm closing the div

how can i refresh the parent page so that the user entered can be show automatically